# Android App Crashing on Phone Boot

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I have the permission to receive boot completed and I have specified which receiver to run.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="xyz.android.MyAlarm" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here is the receiver code

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, InviteService.class);
    context.startService(i);        
}
}
```

And here is a snippet of my InviteService service code

```
public class InviteService extends IntentService {

private String userId;
private SharedPreferences settingsPrefs;

public InviteService() {
    super("InviteService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Utils.isOnline(this)) {
        userId = getSharedPreferences("user-session", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getString("userId", null);
        settingsPrefs = getSharedPreferences(userId, MODE_PRIVATE);

        Log.d("turnOffAlarm",
                "" + settingsPrefs.getBoolean("turnOffAlarm", false));
        if (userId == null
                || settingsPrefs.getBoolean("turnOffAlarm", false)) {
            stopService(intent);
            return;
        }
      }
    }
```

When a user reboots their phone the following error message occurs.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at xyz.android.InviteService.onHandleIntent(InviteService.java:134)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

The line I am getting a null pointer exception on is line that logs the turnOffAlarm. So this is what happening. For some reason userId is getting the value null, when it should be not. This value has been stored in the preferences file and never gives a problem until the phone reboots.

I cannot reproduce this error on the emulator, any suggestions?

Comment: getString("userd", null) - is this a typo in the question or your code (missing I)?

Comment: yes that was a typo, let me fix.